# How to get the width of a TextView?

Tags: android

I tried to resize an image inside a textview (using HTML layout and the image callback), but I could not get the correct width of the view. getWidth() always returns 0 for this view. I am calling the function inside onStart() in the application that contains the TextView.

Thanks for any hints!

RG

Answer (score 0):

It is too early to call `getWidth` in `onStart` as the layout is not created yet. Try doing it in `onMeasure`.

PS. You may want to post some of your code as the question is not completely clear

Comment: So I have to subclass TextView somehow? I am currently finding the view by Id, and that gives me no chance to catch it's onMeasure method. I'll probably try to use the display width.

Comment: You can subclass layout itself and override onMeasure/onLayout - whatever suits you best

Answer (score 0):

You could pop this in onSizeChanged or in onLayout, these are called after the views are created.

Edit: the links seem to break the formatting...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int, int, int, int)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int)